# $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}\otimes _\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$

Tags: tensor-products

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}\otimes _\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ as abelian groups.

I've tried to come up with various maps but gotten nowhere.

Thanks for any help

Comment: ...both are $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You have $\mathbb C\otimes_\mathbb C\mathbb C\cong\mathbb C$; on the other hand $\mathbb R$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Yeah but I am just considering these as abelian groups so this is irrelevant right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$ are both isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. More general, for every $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$ you have $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C}V\cong V\cong\mathbb R\otimes_{\mathbb R}V$ because for any unitary (commutative) ring $A$ and any $A$-module $M$ you have $A\otimes_AM\cong M$.

A proof of this isomorphism.
The function $A\times M\to M:(a,x)\mapsto ax$ is $A$ bilinear, hence it induces a group homomorphism $h:A\otimes_A M\to M:a\otimes x\to ax$. Since $1\in A$ this is surjective, while injectivity follows from $0=h(\sum_ia_i\otimes x_i)=\sum_i a_ix_i$ implies $\sum_ia_i\otimes x_i=1\otimes(\sum_ia_i x_i)=0$.

Comment: Is there a slight subtly here in that we can write a map $f:\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such $f(a\otimes b)=ab$ and then show that this map is injectvive/surjective. However do we also need to check that this map is well defined, which is a problem as we don't know what $a\otimes b$ is and so we have to define $g:\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(a,b)=a\otimes b$ and then use the universal property to show that the map from before actually exists and is well defined?

Comment: I add a proof of this isomorphism in my answer.