# isomorphism of vector space and its tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra

want to prove the following proposition : For any vector space $V$ over finite field $F$ ,

$$V\otimes F \sim V \sim F\otimes V$$

($\sim$ means isomorphism here), with all isomorphisms being induced by the natural basis {1} of F.

Comment: Hint: show that every element of $V \otimes_F F$ can be written (uniquely) in the form $v \otimes 1$. By the way, there is no need to assume $F$ is finite.

Comment: See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/774812/54738

Answer (score 0):

yes,$V\otimes F$ is a vector space spanned by {$\alpha_i\otimes 1$}(it's basis for $V\otimes F$) such that {$\alpha_i$} is a basis for $V$.

now you can construct a isomorphism between them that $\alpha_i\otimes 1\to\alpha_i$.

Comment: Let F=GF(4) and we have V⊗GF(4) and If we consider it as a vector space over GF(2), then the above statment is still true?

Comment: @user146566: In the statement $F$ has to be the field over which one considers $V$ as a vector space, not a larger field. So no, it won't work if you tensor a $GF(2)$ space with $GF(4)$. However if you mean consider the isomorphism of $GF(4)$ vector spaces, and _then_ consider _both sides_ as vector spaces over $GF(2)$ then yes, one gets an isomorphsism (since _every_ isomorphism over a larger field gives an isomorphism over a smaller field when restricting scalars on both sides).

Comment: In fact clear meaning of me is that: Let us consider V and GF(4) as two vector spaces over GF(2), now I want to know V⊗GF(4) is isomorph with V or not? what about the isomorphism between V⊗GF(4) and GF(4)? If so, how can I construct this isomorphism?

Comment: @user146566,no let V=GF(2) then $V\otimes GF(4)$ is isomorph with GF(4) not V=GF(2).